# Slider does not align parallel to other child in Colum

Tags: flutter, flutter-ui

I am trying to build the UI below:

[image]

The child of `Column` widgets does not align parallel with another child.
As I have provided the
`crossAxisAlignment CrossAxisAlignment.start,` but It does not work.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home Page'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Container(
          height: 140,
          width: 380,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Text('ご利用可能額'),
                    SizedBox(width: 10),
                    Icon(Icons.info_outline),
                    SizedBox(width: 160),
                    Text('32322円'),
                  ],
                ),
                SliderTheme(
                  data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
                    trackHeight: 12.0,
                    thumbShape: SliderComponentShape.noOverlay,
                    activeTrackColor: Colors.red,
                    inactiveTrackColor: Colors.grey[500],
                  ),
                  child: Slider(
                    value: 0.8,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      // Add your slider value change logic here
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      '32322円',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[500]),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 220),
                    Text(
                      '32322円',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[500]),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alignment does work. If you open [Flutter Inspector](https://docs.flutter.dev/tools/devtools/inspector) in [DevTools](https://docs.flutter.dev/tools/devtools/overview) and enable [Show Guidelines](https://docs.flutter.dev/tools/devtools/inspector#show-guidelines), it will show you that the `Slider` widget is actually aligned with the other children in the `Column`:

[image: Show Guidelines]

(Another way to check this is to wrap the `Slider` with a `Container` and put a color to that `Container`)

The space that you see to the left and right sides of the `Slider` is from the `Slider` widget itself.

---

You can make the `Slider` aligned with the other widgets by removing the `Padding` that wraps the entire `Column` and put individual paddings to each child except the `Slider`.

Another way is to wrap the `Slider` with `Transform.scale`:

```dart
Transform.scale(
  scaleX: 1.15,
  child: Slider(
    // ...
  ),
)
```

Or if you only want to align the left side of the `Slider`, you can also use `Transform.translate`:

```dart
Transform.translate(
  offset: Offset(-24, 0),
  child: Slider(
    // ...
  ),
)
```